# "Could not calculate the upgrade" error upgrading from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, dependencies, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

Could not calculate the upgrade error upgrading from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

To start, I have a system76 laptop running Ubuntu (installed by System76). I'm attempting to upgrade from 20.04.4 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,267 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,268 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
[snip for brevity]
Fetched 450 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
None

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

[snip for brevity]
Fetched 1,147 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Taking a look at those two logs mentioned, I see the following error in `main.log`

```
2022-08-15 15:15:11,426 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
2022-08-15 15:15:11,577 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: evolution-data-server, gir1.2-gweather-3.0, gnome-control-center, libgirepository-1.0-1, ubuntu-desktop'
2022-08-15 15:15:11,586 DEBUG abort called
```

In `apt.log`, I see many broken packages.

```
$ cat apt.log | grep Broken
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 < 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.6 @ii mK > (< 21.04)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Breaks on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mK > (< 3.37)
Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken fuse3:amd64 Breaks on fuse:amd64 < 2.9.9-3 -> 2.9.9-5ubuntu3 @ii umU >
Broken libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 Conflicts on libappindicator3-1:amd64 < 12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1 -> 12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umU >
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken libtss2-mu0:amd64 Breaks on libtss2-esys0:amd64 < 2.3.2-1 @ii mK > (< 3.0.1-2)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-samba:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-common-bin:amd64 Depends on python3-samba:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR NPb >
Broken system76-power:amd64 Conflicts on power-profiles-daemon:amd64 < none -> 0.10.1-3 @un uN >
Broken gdb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken libpython3-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10-dev:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.4-1~)
Broken libgupnp-av-1.0-3:amd64 Breaks on libgupnp-av-1.0-2:amd64 < 0.12.11-2 @ii mK > (< 0.14)
Broken libsepol-dev:amd64 Breaks on libsepol1-dev:amd64 < 3.0-1ubuntu0.1 @ii mK Ib > (< 3.2)
Broken gir1.2-unity-7.0:amd64 Conflicts on gir1.2-unity-5.0:amd64 < 7.1.4+19.04.20190319-0ubuntu3 @ii mK >
Broken python3-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython3-dev:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH > (= 3.10.4-0ubuntu2)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-system76-power:amd64 Depends on system76-power:amd64 < 1.1.22~1659403314~20.04~357f4b0~dev | 1.1.22~1659403314~22.04~357f4b0~dev @ii umR > (>= 1.0.0~)
Broken sssd-ad:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken sssd-ipa:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.15.5~dfsg)
Broken libgupnp-dlna-2.0-4:amd64 Breaks on libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3:amd64 < 0.10.5-4 @ii mK > (< 0.12)
Broken libgc1:amd64 Conflicts on libgc1c2:amd64 < 1:7.6.4-0.4ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken samba:amd64 Depends on python3-samba:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR NPb >
Broken sssd-ad-common:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.15.5~dfsg)
Broken libwacom2:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 -> 2.2.0-1 @ii umU > (= 1.3-2ubuntu3)
Broken system76-driver:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-system76-power:amd64 < 2.0.5~1655914350~20.04~1f055fc~dev | 2.0.5~1655914350~22.04~1f055fc~dev @ii umR >
Broken gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mR > (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken gvfs-bin:amd64 Depends on gvfs-common:amd64 < 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 -> 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1)
Broken libsemanage1:amd64 Depends on libsemanage-common:amd64 < 3.0-1build2 -> 3.3-1build2 @ii umU > (= 3.0-1build2)
Broken python3-crypto:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken sssd:amd64 Depends on sssd-ad:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1 @un uH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 -> 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umU > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gvfs-backends:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.12.0+dfsg)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 -> 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umU > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libwacom2:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 @ii gR > (>= 1.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center-data:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 -> 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU > (< 1:3.37)
Broken gnome-remote-desktop:amd64 Breaks on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:41.4-1ubuntu10)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken libwacom2:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 -> 2.2.0-1 @ii umU > (= 1.3-2ubuntu3)
Broken libwacom9:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 | 2.2.0-1 @ii umH > (= 2.2.0-1)
Broken libmutter-10-0:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken libinput10:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < none | 42.2-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (= 42.2-0ubuntu1)
Broken libwacom-bin:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken libinput-bin:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken xserver-xorg-input-libinput:amd64 Depends on libinput10:amd64 < 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.3 | 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1 @ii umH > (>= 1.19.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken python3-renderpm:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-sss:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-evdev:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-cffi-backend:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-simplejson:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-libxml2:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-tdb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < none | 42.2-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 42~beta)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 < none | 42.2-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 42.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1627671031~20.04~a879ba8~dev | 42.1-1ubuntu3pop0~1651657687~22.04~0386384~dev @ii umR > (>= 3.37.0)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1627671031~20.04~a879ba8~dev | 42.1-1ubuntu3pop0~1651657687~22.04~0386384~dev @ii umR > (>= 3.29)
Broken gdm3:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1627671031~20.04~a879ba8~dev | 42.1-1ubuntu3pop0~1651657687~22.04~0386384~dev @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.37.0)
Broken update-manager:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR >
Broken update-notifier:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.33)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (< 43)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.38)
Broken sssd-common:amd64 Depends on python3-sss:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1 @un ugH >
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR >
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4pop0~1627310541~20.04~1576174~dev | 42.0-1ubuntu6pop1~1650301427~22.04~2055533~dev @ii umR >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 42.2-0ubuntu0.2)
Broken sssd-krb5-common:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1)
Broken sssd-proxy:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1)
Broken sssd-ldap:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1)
Broken sssd-krb5:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4pop0~1627310541~20.04~1576174~dev | 42.0-1ubuntu6pop1~1650301427~22.04~2055533~dev @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 < 33.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42-2~fakesync1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 < 68ubuntu1~20.04.1 | 72~ubuntu5.22.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-session:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umH Ib > (< 40)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii gR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-common:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umU > (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on mutter:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii gR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1627671031~20.04~a879ba8~dev -> 42.1-1ubuntu3pop0~1651657687~22.04~0386384~dev @ii umU > (= 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1627671031~20.04~a879ba8~dev)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-bin:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 -> 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.37)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-common:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 -> 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1)
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umH IPb > (< 3.38.6)
Broken gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umH IPb > (< 42~alpha)
Broken yaru-theme-gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umH IPb > (< 42~)
Broken libgweather-3-16:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umH IPb > (< 40.4-1~)
Broken libgweather-4-0:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umH IPb > (< 40.4-1~)
Broken gnome-startup-applications:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-bin:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umH > (>= 42.0-1ubuntu2)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken gjs:amd64 Depends on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.0-3~ubuntu22.04.2 @ii umH > (= 1.72.0-3~ubuntu22.04.2)
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umH > (>= 42~beta)
Broken ubuntu-settings:amd64 Depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umH > (>= 40)
Broken gnome-calendar:amd64 Depends on libgweather-3-16:amd64 < 3.36.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 | 40.0-5build1 @ii umH > (>= 40.0)
```

I find it difficult to believe these are all broken, but I am not sure the best way to solve this so that I can perform an upgrade.

There are no updates that need to be applied prior to the dist-upgrade

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:6 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease
Hit:8 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:10 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:14 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:12 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease
Hit:15 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

There are no held packages

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
[no output]
```

How do I fix these broken packages?

Comment: did you do a regular upgrade? did you remove all PPAs and packages installed with them (as recommended in the output from do-release-upgrade)?

Comment: I have attempted to do it via to GUI when prompted and received the error at the end of the first snippet. I then attempted via the CLI to try and get a bit more information. It looks like it's telling me to remove some important packages - `ubuntu-desktop` is one. Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` is actually just a metapackage, which contains all the packages installed in a standard Ubuntu installation. Removing it does not remove any of its dependencies (ie any of the packages in the installation). On the other hand, removing any "default" software will prompt the removal of the metapackage, because all of its dependencies are not met. It is not dangerous to remove it itself. However, that is not the solution. Did you do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`? What output did you get from that? Did you actually hold any packages?

Comment: There are no updates to apply and no held packages (output added to question)

Comment: Apologies @Nmath. I was following Ester's comment, though shouldn't have snipped in that case. I've updated the question with the information.

Comment: Having all those ppas greatly increases the challenge of doing a successful upgrade. I don't have nearly as many ppas, but I always `ppa-purge` prior to upgrading and then re-add them after the upgrade is finished.

Comment: PPAs need to be disabled. You also have a `xenial` source which should not be there. Did you change the system's python interpreter? This can break many aspects of the system. Always use virtual environments if you need a different python interpreter for some task- a great deal of the OS relies on the version of python packaged with your system. The release upgrade will only work after all non-canonical sources have been disabled (big C and little c)